# Named Function Expression for recursion

Tags: javascript

As suggested by many people, one of the usages of named function expression is for recursively calling itself. However, it seems that in Chrome Console, function expression without a name can still do so.

Edit : 
I know this is gonna be stackoverflow, however, I would expect a output like `a() is not a function` instead of Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded(…).

```
var a = function () { 
        a();
        }
a();
```

the following function expression with a name should be giving me a Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded(…).

```
var a = function a () { 
           a();
        }
a();
```

Edit 2 : 
In this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function, it says that "If you want to refer to the current function inside the function body, you need to create a named function expression.". However, it seems to me that the statement is no true, because you can still refer to the current function inside the function body without assigning a function identifier to it

Any thoughts would be appreciated

Comment: And your question is....?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, maybe I did not make my question clear. My question is since the `function expression without name` can call itself recursively, why do we need a `named function expresion`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)

Comment: Consider if the expression is not assigned to a variable; `someCallback(function a() { a(); })` vs `someCallback(function () { ??? })`

Comment: so, when you call `a()` - `a` is already function :-) so all correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are reaching the stack limit because there are no conditions to limit the recursion.

```
var a = function (i) { 
        console.log(i);
        if (i >= 10) {
          return;
        }
        else {
          a(++i);
        }
}
a(0);
```

The above is a better example to show an actual working example of this recursion.  Notice how there is a check here whether or not to call the recursive function.  The output would be the following:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

You can also have this logic successfully defined at **parse time**:

```
function a (i) { 
        console.log(i);
        if (i >= 10) {
          return;
        }
        else {
          a(++i);
        }
}
a(0);
```

As for the scope of the function definition, this example shows when `a()` would be defined:

```
if (typeof a === 'undefined') {
  console.log('a is undefined before the definition');
}
else {
  console.log('a is defined before the definition');
}

var a = function () {
  if (typeof a === 'undefined') {
    console.log('a is undefined inside of a');
  }
  else {
    console.log('a is defined inside of a');
  }
}

a();

if (typeof a === 'undefined') {
  console.log('a is undefined after the definition');
}
else {
  console.log('a is defined after the definition');
}
```

The output to this snippet is the following:

```
a is undefined before the definition 
a is defined inside of a 
a is defined after the definition
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  What I meant was that `var a = function () {  a();
   }` is a function expression without name, which is a anonymous function, so it should not be able to refer to itself inside its function. I expected something like a() is not a function in the output

Comment: @XuzhengWang See my edit, that should explain why that is possible.

Comment: Thank you very much, my question lies in the second output, why a is defined inside of a .   In this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function,  it says that "If you want to refer to the current function inside the function body, you need to create a named function expression.". However,  it seems to me that the statement is no true, because you can still refer to the current function inside the function body without assigning a function identifier to it.

Comment: @XuzhengWang, really you refers not to self function, but on variable `a`, so if you assign to it some another value, it break work :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is a really old thread but I will post something similar,
since there is a statement on the book **Javascript: Object Oriented Programming by Kumar Chetan Sharma, Stoyan Stefanov, and Ved Antani**
That says this:
*"Function declaration cannot have recursive calls"*
That statement is wrong or lacks of a more comprehensive explanation because this still does work.

```js
var facto = function(n){
    if(n<=1) return 1;
    return n * facto(n - 1);
}

console.log(facto(3)) // 6
```