# How to sum nested arrays in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I'm trying to create a function that sums the total of all the values in an array, even if those values are nested within nested arrays. Like this:
countArray(array); -->  28 (1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7)
I tried this recursive function, but it just concatenates.

```js
var countArray = function(array){
      var sum=0;
      for(let i=0; i<array.length; i++){
              if(array[i].isArray){
               array[i]=countArray(array[i]);
      }
    
          sum+=array[i];
        
        }
      
      return sum;
}
```

Comment: Share the array content for better understanding.

Comment: `array[i].isArray` - there isn't an `isArray` property on objects/arrays. There is [`Array.isArray()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sum all integers in a multidimensional array javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33665228/sum-all-integers-in-a-multidimensional-array-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

Flatten the array using [`Array.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat), and then sum using [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
const countArray = array => 
  array.flat(Infinity)
    .reduce((sum, n) => sum + n, 0)

console.log(countArray([1, 2, [3, [4, 5], 6], 7]));
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `Array.isArray` to check if an object is an array.
2. Add the result of the recursive call to the sum each time.

```js
var countArray = function(array) {
  var sum = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (Array.isArray(array[i])) {
      sum += countArray(array[i]);
    } else {
      sum += array[i];
    }
  }
  return sum;
}
console.log(countArray([1, 2, [3, [4, 5], 6], 7]));
```

You could also use `Array#reduce` with a recursive function.

```js
const countArray = array => array.reduce((acc,curr)=>
   acc + (Array.isArray(curr) ? countArray(curr) : curr), 0);
console.log(countArray([1, 2, [3, [4, 5], 6], 7]));
```

This problem can be simplified to finding the sum of all elements in a one-dimensional array by using `Array#flat` beforehand.

```js
const countArray = array => array.flat(Infinity).reduce((acc,curr)=>acc+curr, 0);
console.log(countArray([1, 2, [3, [4, 5], 6], 7]));
```

Answer (score 1):

Beside the problem of right application of [`Array.isArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray), you have an actual use case for taking a [named function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32950161/named-function-expression-for-recursion), because you call the function recursively and by uzsing just a variable, the reference of the function could go.

```
function countArray(array) {
    var sum = 0;
    for (const value of array) {
        sum += Array.isArray(value) ? countArray(value) : value;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your working example:

```js
const arr = [1, [2, [3]]]

const countArray = function(array) {
  let sum = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (Array.isArray(array[i])) {
      sum += countArray(array[i]);
    } else {
      sum += array[i];
    }
  }

  return sum;
}

console.log(countArray(arr));
```

A little bit simplified example:

```js
const arr = [1, [2, [3]]]

const countArray = (array) => {
  let sum = 0;

  for (const el of array) {
    sum += Array.isArray(el) ? countArray(el) : el
  }

  return sum;
}

console.log(countArray(arr));
```

Even more simple code:

```js
const arr = [1, [2, [3]]]

const countArray = (array) =>
  array.reduce((sum, el) =>
    Array.isArray(el) ? sum + countArray(el) : sum + el, // reduce function
    0); // sum = 0 intialization

console.log(countArray(arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using ramda:

const sumNested = compose(sum, flatten)